# How to get object value inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

This is my code for generating the chart:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
            {
                var dataChart = {
                    "series_data":[
                        {"name":"Brunei Darussalam","data":[1]},
                        {"name":"Saudi Arabia","data":[1]},
                        {"name":"Singapore","data":[2]},
                        {"name":"Malaysia","data":[3]},
                        {"name":"Korea","data":[3]},
                        {"name":"Taiwan","data":[5]}],
                    "total":[{"total":15}]
                };
                var option = {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Jumlah Registrasi'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: '*berdasarkan negara tujuan*'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        visible: false
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Jumlah'
                        },
                        allowDecimals: false,
                        minRange: 1,
                        tickInterval: 1
                    },
                    labels: {
                       items:[{
                         html: 'Total: '+dataChart.total, // this is the problem that im having now
                           style: {
                              left: '400px',
                              top: '10px'
                           }
                       }]
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            },
                            enableMouseTracking: false
                        }
                    },
                    series: ''
                };

                option.chart.renderTo = 'negara';
                option.series   = dataChart.series_data;
                var chartNegara = new Highcharts.Chart(option);
            });
```

As you can see there're 2 array in var dataChart, series_data and total. The total is the sum of the series_data. So i have a problem how to show this total number into the chart.

Here's my jsfiddle for my code: https://jsfiddle.net/HealMee/pq30un8f/1

The error im having now is :

```
Total: [object Object]
```

Comment: It does not matter where the data is coming from, this is still a jQuery/Highcharts JavaScript issue that has nothing to do with PHP.  Edited tags.

Comment: @Sparky yeah i shouldn't have mention where the data is coming from. I think my problem is how to get the total value from the var dataChart

Comment: Does Highcharts even give you an option to put something there?

Comment: So it's solved then, isn't it?

Comment: @Bla... no, it doesnt, the generated chart shows like this. Total: [object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `chart` into something like below:

```js
chart: {
  type: 'column',
    borderWidth: 1,
      events: {
        load: function(event) {
          var total = dataChart.total[0].total;
          var text = this.renderer.text(
            'Total: ' + total,
            this.plotLeft,
            this.plotTop - 20
          ).attr({
            zIndex: 5
          }).add()
          }
      }
},
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pq30un8f/2/).. Cheers.

Comment: the var dataChart is coming from MVC controller that contain 2 arrays, series_data and total. so its in one package. the raw code is like this. `var dataChart = <?php echo $negara ?>;`

Comment: i think your solution might work, but how to get the total value from the `dataChart`? maybe like this? `var total = dataChart.total` (this doesnt work) or something?

Comment: I found a way to get the value, I edited your answer from `var total = 15;` to  `var total = dataChart.total[0].total;` and this is solve my problem